# class not found in web.php line 5

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'System\Libary\Route' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\routes\web.php:5 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php(4): include() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\routes\web.php on line 5 in PHP

Comment: Without any code it is difficult to know what to say.

Answer (score 0):

Detail your problem, what you're trying to do. Thus, we will be able to help better!

Probably, some library is missing that should be installed via composer.
You will probably have a file called composer.json in the same directory, so try to install the composer by following the instructions: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Then, open the CMD, access the project folder and install the dependencies as [instructed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies), with the command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Then call it in the script on start:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```